# MySQL never runs the one-hour event

Tags: mysql

can anyone help to figure out if the following event is wrong or it's MySQL issue because it was successfully created and MySQL shows the event's status is 'Enabled', but the event never runs as it's supposed to be

```
CREATE EVENT `db_name`.`event_name`
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

DO
  update `db_name`.table set table.field = (table.field + ((RAND()*10)));
```

Comment: There was no problem with the SQL statement 'Update', it was tested

Comment: Have you [switched on the event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events-configuration.html) (you can check with `SHOW PROCESSLIST`)?

Comment: That said, incrementing the values in a column by random amounts every minute is a very strange thing to want to do.  What business problem are you trying to solve with this scheduled event?

Comment: what I'm supposed to see when I run SHOW PROCRSSLIST? I don's see anything related to the event 'event_name'

Comment: As shown in the manual entry to which my previous comment linked, if the event scheduler is switched on then you will see a process running command `Daemon` under the user `event_scheduler`.

Comment: Thanks eggyal, it was an issue with MySQL permissions, problem fixed